# vb.NET to C# conversion error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'MyCustomObject' An explicit conversion exists

Tags: c#, vb.net, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to convert some VB.net code I found online to some C# code but I'm getting the following error around this line of code in my C# code:

```
DNNServiceSecurityToken token = DataCache.GetCache("DNNServiceSecurityToken_" + TokenId.ToString());
```

The specific error code is:

### Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' 
 to 'MyTypes.DNNServiceSecurityToken'. 
 An explicit conversion exists 
 (are you missing a cast?)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
    using DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities;
    using DotNetNuke.Entities.Users;
    using MyTypes;

        public class SecurityTokenInspector : IParameterInspector
        {
            public string Roles;

            public SecurityTokenInspector(string value)
            {
                Roles = value;
            }

            public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
            {

                // token will always be the last parameter 
                int index = inputs.Length - 1;
                string TokenId = inputs[index].ToString();

                // ********** ERROR LINE BELOW HERE *********** //
                // THE ERROR IS HAPPENING WITH THIS LINE:       //
                // ******  first make sure token exists  ****** //
                DNNServiceSecurityToken token = DataCache.GetCache("DNNServiceSecurityToken_" + TokenId.ToString());
                if (token == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Security Token Expired. Please request a new Token");
                }

                // if token exists, check user roles 
                UserInfo user = UserController.GetUserById(0, token.UserID);
                if (!(user.IsInRole(Roles)))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Access Denied. Role Membership Requirements not met");
                    return null;
                }

                return null;

            }

            public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
            {
                return;
            }

        }
```

```
Imports System 
 Imports System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher 
 Imports DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities 
 Imports DotNetNuke.Entities.Users 

 Public Class SecurityTokenInspector 
    Implements IParameterInspector 

    Public Roles As String 

    Public Sub New(ByVal value As String) 
       Roles = value 
    End Sub 

    Public Function BeforeCall(ByVal operationName As String, _ 
       ByVal inputs() As Object) As Object _ 
       Implements IParameterInspector.BeforeCall 

       ' token will always be the last parameter 
       Dim index As Integer = inputs.Length - 1 
       Dim TokenId As String = inputs(index).ToString() 

       ' first make sure token exists 
       Dim token As DNNServiceSecurityToken = 
          _DataCache.GetCache("DNNSecurityToken_" & TokenId) 
       If token Is Nothing Then 
          Throw New Exception( _ 
          "Security Token Expired. Please request a new Token") 
       End If 

       ' if token exists, check user roles 
       Dim user As UserInfo = UserController.GetUserById(0, token.UserID) 
       If Not user.IsInRole(Roles) Then 
          Throw New Exception( _ 
          "Access Denied. Role Membership Requirements not met") 
          Return Nothing 
       End If 

        Return Nothing 

    End Function 

    Public Sub AfterCall(ByVal operationName As String, _ 
       ByVal outputs() As Object, ByVal returnValue As Object, _ 
       ByVal correlationState As Object) _ 
       Implements IParameterInspector.AfterCall 
       Return 
    End Sub 

 End Class
```

Comment: I recommend you read a good C# book or tutorial.  This is basic casting.

Comment: you are right, I have only been learning C# for the last month, but thanks for the obvious suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast the return object to the object type of your variable:

```
DNNServiceSecurityToken token = (DNNServiceSecurityToken) DataCache.GetCache("DNNServiceSecurityToken_" + TokenId.ToString());
```

Comment: If he does this, then won't an exception be thrown if the types don't match and the user doesn't want that as he explicitly checks for null after that line.  The better solution in this case is to use the as operator?

Answer (score 2):

Try casting it as the error suggests:

```
DNNServiceSecurityToken token = DataCache.GetCache("DNNServiceSecurityToken_" + TokenId.ToString()) as DNNServiceSecurityToken;
```

Comment: @user1287306 really, ok, assumed that would work as you are then checking for null afterwards which is a common pattern when using as.

Comment: Maybe DNNServiceSecurityToken is a value type?

Comment: @Murven ummm ok.  Then surely the check for null after that is irrelevant if we assume the type returned is always a DNNServiceSecurityToken.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the token to be a DNNServiceSecurityToken?  Or will the type returned by GetCache work just as well?

Try this:

```
var token = DataCache.GetCache("DNNServiceSecurityToken_" + TokenId.ToString());
```